# Python program not writing anything to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Got thrown on this project with little python experience. Trying to write from an encoder to a csv. Weird thing is that the program wont even write a string into the file. Any advice is appreciated!

```
while not file_passed:
try:
    file_name = input("Enter log file name: ")
    
    # Add extension if not already given
    if "." not in file_name:
        file_name += ".csv"
        
    log_file = open(file_name, "a")
    print("log file open debug passed")
    
    # Add header row to log file
    if os.stat(log_file.name).st_size == 0:
        log_file.write("time (ms), pressure, angle(rad) \n")
        print("Logged header to file")
    file_passed = True
except:
    print("Invalid file, or could not open the file specified.\n-----")
```

Here is a snippet of what I have narrowed it down to I believe. You can see my little debug testing statements to see if its breaking into the correct if statements. It does print all of the debug statements so it seems to be breaking into the if with log_file.write("time(ms), pressure, angle(rad) \n")

EDIT: Tried adding a with before log_file.write("") line, program crashes on start when added. Here is the code in its entirety as I should have added to begin with my bad

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime
import os

pressure_passed = False
arduino_passed = False
file_passed = False

BAUD_RATE = 115200

GARBAGE_CYCLES = 3 # how many cycles to ignore before logging data
garbage_cycle = 0

# Save data to log file
def LogData(startTime, pressureData, arduinoData, file):
    global garbage_cycle
    
    if garbage_cycle < GARBAGE_CYCLES:
        garbage_cycle += 1
    else:
        delta = datetime.now() - startTime
        ms = delta.total_seconds() * 1000
        dataString = "{:0.2f}, {}, {}\n".format(ms, pressureData, arduinoData)
        file.write(dataString)
        print(dataString, end = "")



# Get the COM port for the Mark-10 Series 5
while not pressure_passed:
    try:
        pressure_com = input("Enter Mark-10 Series 5 COM Port #: ")
        pressure_ser = serial.Serial("COM" + str(pressure_com), BAUD_RATE)
        pressure_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid COM Port, please enter a valid port.\n-----")



# Get the COM port for the Arduino 
while not arduino_passed:
    try:
        arduino_com = input("Enter Ardunio COM Port #: ")
        arduino_ser = serial.Serial("COM" + str(arduino_com), BAUD_RATE)
        arduino_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid COM Port, please enter a valid port.\n-----")
    
    
    
# Get the name for the log file
while not file_passed:
    try:
        file_name = input("Enter log file name: ")
        
        # Add extension if not already given
        if "." not in file_name:
            file_name += ".csv"
            
        log_file = open(file_name, "a")
        
        # Add header row to log file
        if os.stat(log_file.name).st_size == 0:
            log_file.write("time (ms), pressure, angle (deg)\n")
            
        file_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid file, or could not open the file specified.\n-----")
        
        
start = datetime.now()
        
# Variables to read serial input
pressure_data = ""
last_pressure = ""
arduino_data = ""
last_arduino = ""

# Main program loop
# Serial is read from byte by byte to better sync the two devices
while True:
    try:
        x_changed = False
        y_changed = False
        
        # Read from Mark-10 serial if available
        # x is a byte read from the serial line, converted to ascii
        if pressure_ser.in_waiting > 0:
            x = pressure_ser.read().decode('ascii')
            x_changed = True
        
        # Read from Arduino serial if available
        # y is a byte read from the serial line, converted to ascii
        if arduino_ser.in_waiting > 0:
            y = arduino_ser.read().decode('ascii')
            y_changed = True
        
        # If new data received, check if we should log it
        if x_changed:
            if x == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
                if last_pressure != pressure_data:
                    LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)
                    
                last_pressure = pressure_data
                pressure_data = ""
            elif x != '\r': # Otherwise, add the read character to the string
                pressure_data += x
                
        if y_changed:
            if y == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
                if last_arduino != arduino_data:
                    LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)
                    
                last_arduino = arduino_data
                arduino_data = ""
            elif y != '\r': # Otherwise, add the read character to the string
                arduino_data += y
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if arduino_ser.isOpen():
            arduino_ser.close()
        if pressure_ser.isOpen():
            pressure_ser.close()
        log_file.close()
        break
```

Comment: Am not seeing `with log_file.write("time(ms), pressure, angle(rad)...` in your code. Also not seeing where you are closing file.

Comment: The file is actively logging data so it should only close when an error occurs of the user closes the command line. This is just a snippet of it, there is an exception later on where if any of the serial ports are removed it closes the program, Other than that no closes exist. Where should one be if they need to be anywhere else? Also I will attempt the with log_file now. Thank you!

Comment: Until you explicitly `close()` the file the content will not be seen by other programs. Create an simple example that appends to a file without closing and examine the content before and after closing the file. If you want to log to a file use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#module-logging) module.